# CMake pass environment variable to ExternalProject_Add

Tags: makefile, cmake, mbedtls

I'm trying to pass an environment variable to an external project in my `CMakeLists.txt` without any success.

In this case, I have a dependency to `mbedtls` library which is downloaded and built in my cmake. In Linux this works as intended, however in a Windows environment, I need to pass a variable WINDOWS_BUILD=1 to the make environment.

I have tried to add a `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` to a batch file which sets this environment variable in the `ExternalProject_Add()`, however this does not work. If I manually go into the automatically downloaded mbedtls folder and write

```
$ make WINDOWS_BUILD=1
```

it works as intended, however I want to build everything from CMake environment. Any takes?

Comment: Just write `make WINDOWS_BUILD=1` as a `BUILD_COMMAND`. Note, that the variable here is not an environment, but a `make` one. (Command for passing environment variable would be `WINDOWS_BUILD=1 make`.)

Comment: How are you calling the external project? If you use the `execute_process` [command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html), it lets you pass arguments right in the call